# Where is the source code for Express JS' session.generate() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am trying to understand some code about session storage and generation in Express JS and Node.js:

```
Store.prototype.regenerate = function(req, fn){
  var self = this;
  this.destroy(req.sessionID, function(err){
    self.generate(req);
    fn(err);
  });
};
```

In the above [piece of code](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/e21cc9b52be1ccd5c7ef6158e406f62d9f0e0fa4/session/store.js), there is a call to a `generate()` function. I can't find the corresponding code for this function, where is it? What does it do? I could not find it in the `EventEmitter` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generate()` is defined in express-session [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/6cc95c9f161ab6f14cab264e196c78d22248404c/index.js#L87-L91). As you can see, it generates the session ID as well as the session instance object and the session cookie to be sent to the client.